# Does it make sense to create a uniqueID for this MySQL table in a database?

Tags: mysql, database

I’m currently trying to design my table structures for a made up database.  The database will have three separate tables and track the populations of cities for 10 years.  After every year, population figures will be added for each city in the database.  Here is how I’ve laid out my three tables so far:

Cities (city_id, city_name, city_abbrv)

Year (year_id, year)

Stats (year_id, city_id, population)

I’m worried about not having a unique identifier in my Stats table.  With 10 cities, the year data will be the same for 10 entries.  Once I enter multiple years of data, the city_id will be reused.  In my research on this site I’ve read that having a unique ID for every table is not required but the book I’m using to learn database design (while brief) never mentions that this is okay.  I would like to know the best way to design a database that receivers data entries for the same group of things on a daily/weekly/monthly/yearly schedule.  Should I add in a unique_id column to my Stats table?  Or would this be a wasted column?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why don't you just use `(year_id, city_id)` as primary key? BTW: `year_id` in the `Year` table is a wasted column. You can use `year` as primary key.

Comment: I was worried about not having a unique identifier in the Stats table.  If I use year_id and city_id as the primary keys I'd have no unique identifier in the Stats table.

Comment: You can use a combination of two (or more) columns as a "unique identifier" (composite primary key).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need each of those tables to have the column id as [primary key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html).

A primary key is used to uniquely identify a table row. A primary key cannot be NULL since NULL is not a value. So basically those columns will be unique yes.

Question: Why you need primary keys in your tables?

Answer:

- If you are looking to select data from different tables you are opting for join so you need keys to use for that join.
- If you want your
  table to be clustered, you need some kind of a primary key.

Side Note: You may need to get familiar with indexing columns, see [advantages of indexing](https://www.bayt.com/en/specialties/q/59171/what-are-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-indexing-in-database/).

---

```
Cities (id, city_name, city_abbrv) //with id as primary key

Year (id, year) //with id as primary key

Stats (id, year_id, city_id, population) //with id as primary key 
//And year_id and city_id as foregin key connected by their respective ids
```

If you are still beginner with MYSQL see the [W3school tutorial for SQL primary keys](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp).

Comment: Yes, that makes complete sense.  I was thinking that city_id and year_id would be the primary keys in my Cities and Year tables.  I'm just a bit lost when it comes to creating a primary key for my Stats table.  I'm unsure of how to make it so I can uniquely identify a table row in my Stats table.  Should I simply create another column called unique_id and have it auto increment with every entry?

Comment: I'll edit my answer now  and I try my best to explain the right structure for the problem.

Comment: It is done, please recheck my answer.

Comment: Yes this makes sense.  You're saying that I should add an ID column to my Stats table to create a unique identifier for each row...correct?  If so, thanks for taking a look and making a suggestion!  Appreciate the help!

Comment: Yes make it a primary key MySQL will automatically make it unique for you ;) Follow exactly those statements and you are good.